# Freebsd ssh gives no prompt

Tags: ssh, freebsd

I'm trying to connect to a FreeBsd machine via ssh, but get no prompt in a client. I have changed these options in sshd_config:

```
Port 253
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

It is possible to login locally to 127.0.0.1, but I get no prompt when trying to do it remotely. Please, tell me what else shell I check?
update:
ssh -vvv gives the following:

```
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "x.x.x.x" port 253
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 253.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pilyak/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pilyak/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
```

and hangs after this

Comment: Is the typo `PassworAuthentication` intentional?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo in my post, but not in the config. Corrected it.

Comment: Firewall? telnet from client to FreeBSD box port 253

Comment: Does it make sense to check if sockstat shows the connection established? Sockstat shows connection until I quit the client.

Comment: Try to run `ssh -v` from a remote host to see if ssh negotiation started.

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the problem was on the client-side - somewhere deep package inspection is used to prevent outgoing SSH from the office network. Thanks everyone for trying to help. I was confused by the fact that connection was established and didn't think that packet filtering causes the issue.